# FIFO Queue with Polars DataFrame

Tags: python-polars, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm currently working on a use case that involves the usage of sensors and IoT data in the form of a (multivariate) time series. The final goal is to produce an ML model for fault/anomaly detection.
The dataset is pretty big, and Polars works exceptionally well for the offline EDA/preprocessing phase.
However, some of the feature engineering operations we are doing offline, we want to replicate them online. That is, once the model is deployed, a stream of data will continuously arrive, and on this stream we need to:

- Preprocess the data (e.g. scaling).
- Compute extra features.
- Pass the features to the model.

Most of the preprocessing/feature engineering operations are based on moving windows.
Moving windows are very easy to use offline, but when you move to the online setting, you need to keep in memory a buffer of data of the correct size to replicate the same computations.

Here is a trivial example that assumes that all the window operations are based on a window of size 4 (where 4 is the number of rows in a DataFrame):

```py
>>> import polars as pl

>>> window_size = 4 # window size used to compute features.

# Suppose that, at the beginning, we have the following dataframe

>>> buffer = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[11,12,13,14]})
>>> buffer
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 11  │
│ 2   ┆ 12  │
│ 3   ┆ 13  │
│ 4   ┆ 14  │
└─────┴─────┘

# Next, we do something with the dataframe. For example, we compute a rolling mean:

>>> X = buffer.with_columns(pl.all().rolling_mean(window_size)).drop_nulls()

>>> X
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 2.5 ┆ 12.5 │
└─────┴──────┘

# Then, we pass the computed features to a model:

>>> model.predict(X.to_pandas())

# After some time, another batch of data arrives. 
# This batch can contain one or multiple rows.

>>> new_df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[5,6], 'b':[15,16]})

# Now we update the buffer.
# The new buffer should contain the new data and only the old data 
# required to replicate the moving window operation.
# That is, we set the length of the buffer such that the length of X (the aggregated dataframe) 
# is the same as the length of new_df.

>>> buffer = pl.concat((buffer, new_df)).tail(window_size + len(new_df) - 1)

>>> buffer
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 12  │
│ 3   ┆ 13  │
│ 4   ┆ 14  │
│ 5   ┆ 15  │
│ 6   ┆ 16  │
└─────┴─────┘

# Repeat the same operation:

>>> X = buffer.with_columns(pl.all().rolling_mean(window_size)).drop_nulls()
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 3.5 ┆ 13.5 │
│ 4.5 ┆ 14.5 │
└─────┴──────┘

>>> len(X) == len(new_df)
True

# continue
```

The structure naively implemented above is essentially a FIFO queue. Where the length of the queue is set to be `window_size + length_of_batch - 1`.

I'm not sure this problem is best solved directly with Polars or with Pyarrow tools. What do you think is the most efficient way of implementig this structure with Polars DataFrames (or Arrow buffers)?

Thanks a lot!